# Получить id объекта с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery

есть кусок html

```
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-1' style='width:60px'>Год:</div>
      <div class='col-md-5' style='margin-top:-25px'>
        <ul id='year' class='pagination'>
            <li class='active' id='2016' onclick='year(this.id);'><a href='#'>2016</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-1' style='width:60px'>Неделя:</div>
      <div class='col-md-5' style='margin-top:-17px'>
        <ul id='week' class='pagination'>
            <li id='2' onclick='week(this.id);'><a href='#'>2</a></li>
            <li id='3' class='active' onclick='week(this.id);'><a href='#'>3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Пытаюсь получить значение активной недели

```
$("#week ul li.active").attr('id');
```

получаю 2016, т.е. показывает год, а не неделю.
Не могу понять в чем косяк.

Comment: можете пример на jsfiddle сделать? судя по коду вам ничего не должно было вывестись ни год ни неделю

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В  html ошибка: `3</a>/li>`, а должно быть `3</a></li>`

Чтобы получить 3, пишете так:

```
var v = $("#week .active").text();
```

или так

```
var v = $("#week .active").attr("id"):
```

если на странице несколько тегов с id="week", и надо получить последний, то так

```
var v = $("#week .active").last().attr("id");
```

---

**UPDATE**

Т.к. в селекторе `"#week .active"` не указан тег `li`, то селектор будет работать, даже если изменить html на следующий:

```
<div class='col-md-5' style='margin-top:-17px' id='week' >
  <div id='5' class='active' onclick='week(this.id);'><a href='#'>5</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Это все из-за не правильного селектора

```
$("#week ul li.active")
```

данный селектор ищет список `ul` **внутри** элемента с `id="week"`. А у вас сам `ul` имеет этот `id`.

Таким образом, нужно изменить этот селектор, сказав что мы ищем именно `ul` с таки id

```
$("ul#week li.active")
```

либо вообще опустить `ul`

```
$("#week li.active")
```

так как id должен быть уникальным на странице этого селектора достаточно

---

Что касается

> получаю 2016, т.е. показывает год, а не неделю.

судя по предоставленному куску кода - вывод вашего селектора должен быть *undefined*.
Если вы получаете именно `2016`, можно предположить, что данный кусок кода расположен внутри контейнера с `id="week"`, т.е. на странице у вас как минимум два элемента с таким id.

Пример

```js
console.log($("#week ul li.active").attr('id'));
$('body').append($("#week ul li.active").attr('id'));
console.log($("#week ul li.active"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="week">

  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-1' style='width:60px'>Год:</div>
    <div class='col-md-5' style='margin-top:-25px'>
      <ul id='year' class='pagination'>
        <li class='active' id='2016' onclick='year(this.id);'><a href='#'>2016</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-1' style='width:60px'>Неделя:</div>
    <div class='col-md-5' style='margin-top:-17px'>
      <ul id='week' class='pagination'>
        <li id='2' onclick='week(this.id);'><a href='#'>2</a></li>
        <li id='3' class='active' onclick='week(this.id);'><a href='#'>3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: $("#week li.active") выводит 20163. 
заработало $("ul#week li.active")

Comment: @thecoder, а какая версия jQuery используется? Так же обратите внимание на дополнение в вопросе

Comment: jquery 1.11.3. Оказалась, что на странице два контейнера с id='week', исправил и код $("#week li.active") сработал. Надо быть внимательнее.

Comment: _"либо вообще опустить ul"_ -- а li для чего отставили?

Comment: @Stack, потому что класс может быть на любом вложенном элементе

Comment: _"потому что класс может быть на любом вложенном элементе"_ -- именно поэтому можно не указывать имя тега. и li указывать не надо. посмотрите мой ответ.

Comment: @Stack, я имел ввиду, что внутри `li`с классом `active` может быть другой элемент с этим же классом, но нам нужен именно `li` так как по разметке id нужно брать именно у него.

Comment: _"что внутри liс классом active может быть другой элемент с этим же классом,"_ -- не думаю, что будут одинаковые li с одинаковыми active. а как их тогда различать? по смыслу - active - должен быть один в #week

Comment: @Stack, не понял как ваш комментарий относится к цитате в нем

Comment: _"не понял как ваш комментарий относится к цитате в нем"_ -- вы сказали что используете `li.active`, потому что _"может быть другой элемент с этим же классом"_ -- а я говорю, что в ul два li с class=active - не будет, если руки не кривые.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34588/discussion-between-grundy-and-stack).

Answer (score 4):

У вас здесь ошибка:

```
$("#week ul li.active").attr('id');
```

ID `week` это и есть список `ul`, должно быть так:

```
$("#week li.active").attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Эх.. Никто не вспоминает про `prop`...

```
$("#week .active").prop('id');
```

Comment: attr работает с html, а prop работает - с dom. из-за prop может быть путаница. т.к. не все атрибуты из html транслируются в dom

Comment: @Stack, да они работают с разными вещами и предназначены для разных целей. В данном случае они оба будут работать, но в общем случае заменять `prop` на `attr` даже для того, что есть в атрибутах, неверно.